# Audio Player disappear after setUrl on iPhone for Ext.Audio

Tags: iphone, sencha-touch

I'm trying to update the audio url programmatically and according to the debugging its working but the problem is that the player disappear after updating the url and all I get is a blank page.
This happens only when I use the code on iPhone simulator or iPhone, the code is working properly on Safari.

Code:

```
Ext.define('senchaApp.view.AudioPage',{    
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype:'audioPageView',
    requires:[
           'Ext.Audio'
    ],
config:{
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: {
        type : 'vbox',
        pack : 'center',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'audio',
            cls: 'myAudio',
            id:'audioss',
            url  : './file.mp3',
            loop: true,
        }
    ],
           listeners:{
                painted:function()
                {                        
                    Ext.getCmp('audioss').setUrl('./file2.mp3'); 
                    console.log(Ext.getCmp('audioss').getUrl());
                }
           }       
    }  
});
```

Any idea about the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Hamurabi try this into event,

```
Ext.getCmp('audioss').play()
```

I hope this helps. :) Ciao

Comment: Hi, I did tried that and didn't work. However I posted the same question on Sencha Forums and here is the answer: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?222766-Ext.Audio-setUrl-problem-on-iPhone